# Hosting with a Node web app

Tags: node.js, heroku

I'm new to node and I'm under the assumption that node applications have to be hosted with either AWS, Heroku, Digital Ocean, etc. So I'm not able to continue using the GoDaddy hosting I'm currently using correct?

Comment: It depends upon what GoDaddy service you have.

Comment: Read this: [GoDaddy revamps Node.js Web infrastructure with a little Nodejitsu](https://sdtimes.com/domain-hosting/godaddy-revamps-node-js-web-infrastructure-with-a-little-nodejitsu/) and this: [GoDaddy Cloud Servers: Set up Node.js application for production](https://www.godaddy.com/help/set-up-nodejs-application-for-production-24696)

Answer (score 0):

I'd call Godaddy's customer service so they can tell you what you can do and cannot do. They're very restrictive, but if you have a domain name with them, it's easy to use other hosting at least. Their DNS services are pretty reliable and they have a lot of wikis and how-to's